# Loop through lines of file and add continuing numbers

Tags: bash, loops, sed, count

I try to modify lines in a file, where each line is a command and I need to provide continuing numbers as parameters to the different lines.

> BestFirst --> BestFirst -D 5 -N 5
>
> BestFirst --> BestFirst -D 5 -N 10
>
> BestFirst --> BestFirst -D 5 -N 15
>
> ...
>
> BestFirst --> BestFirst -D 10 -N 15
>
> ...
>
> BestFirst --> BestFirst -D 100 -N 100

I tried to start with the `-N` option but did not succeed with this:

```
counter=5; while read line; do echo $line | sed -e  "s/BestFirst/BestFirst -D 5 -N $counter/"; counter=$[ counter+5 ]; done < attribute_selectors_cfssubeval_bestfirst_various_parameters.csv
```

This returns more or less the right thing but does not modify the file itself.

How can I modify the file the right way?

Comment: Is the original file really just the string "BestFirst" repeated multiple times? It seems like it would be faster to just generate the entire file from scratch with an appropriate `awk` script rather than calling `sed` on each line of the input file individually.

Comment: @chepner I am quite sure that you are right, I saw some solutions to similar problems with awk. I just did not understand awk well enough to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to determine the output file in your sed command. Try the following:

```
counter=5; while read line; do echo $line | sed -e  "s/BestFirst/BestFirst -D 5 -N $counter/" >> result.csv; counter=$[ counter+5 ]; done < attribute_selectors_cfssubeval_bestfirst_various_parameters.csv
```

The results will be in the file results.csv

**EDIT:** If you wanted to modify the same file you are reading of: i don't think that is a good idea. You could rename the result file after deleting the source if you want the file to have the exact same name.

Comment: Concerning your EDIT: I did exactly that. Modify or create a second and rename - wasn't much additional effort